# Calculating correlation among different scales

Tags: correlation, pearson-r, scales

I have conducted a small scale study investigating teachers mental health, covid-19 anxiety, work engagement and burn out levels. Now I would like to measure the relationships between the aforementioned scales. I calculated the mean score for each scale and run a simple Pearson’s correlation. I am wondering though if this approach is too simplistic. Is this the best approach when measuring different Likert-type scale questionnaires?

Comment: Thanks, Nick, not really the answer I was looking for though!

Comment: If not, then editing your question to add focus or detail seems advised, as it is not getting much attention.